# Why is it allowed to abbreviate std::begin(v) to begin(v) as parameters of std::find()?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

I got this example from cpp reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find:

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
auto result2 = std::find(begin(v), end(v), 2);
```

My first intent would have to be that both arguments begin(v) and end(v) must have the namespace specifier prefixed: `std::begin(v)` and `std::end(v)`. But apparently according to the example it is also possible to leave this out. Why can I do this, in which situations can I do this and what C++ standard does this feature ship with?

Comment: what is `v`? Please include a [mcve]. Depending on the type of `v` this can work or this can not work

Comment: This is unrelated to `std::find`.

Comment: @rafix07: I searched for ADL beforehand but as it seems ADL implies the namespace of the calling function from its arguments, but in this case its the other way around: the namespace of the function arguments are implied from the calling function. So its technically not "Argument" dependent lookup.

Comment: @glades No. It *is* ADL, and the presence of `std::find` is irrelevant. It works the same without.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: how do you mean without?
As I understand it, _Argument_ dependend lookup limits the set of possible namespaces for the calling  function to the one of its arguments. So afaik ADL would be the other way around:
find(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 2).
Can you elaborate where it states that ADL would also work vice-versa?

Comment: It doesn't work vice-versa. `v` is the argument, its type is in namespace `std`, so `begin(v)` resolves to `std::begin(v)`. The `std::find` is immaterial here.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Ahh of course that makes sense! Thanks! Could I then leave off the std:: from find as well?

Comment: Can't say for sure. `std::vector` can use plain pointers as iterator types. If it does, ADL won't work here (`int*` has no associated namespace). It can even change between build configurations (I've seen code relying on ADL build in debug mode, only to not build in release mode).